# How to prevent rerender a component which gets props from consumer props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
import {
    Consumer,
    IFormConsumer
} from "react-context-form/src";
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from "react";
import Table from './table';
import {Modal} from './modal'
interface ListProps{
    // list props
}

interface TargetProps{
    // target props
}

interface ValueProps {
    // value props
}

interface ReturnProps {
    // return props
}

export const List: FunctionComponent<ListProps> = ({
    readOnly = false
}) => {
    const [formModalOpen, setFormModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const onFormCancel = () => {
        setFormModalOpen(false)
};
    const [targetRow, setTargetRow] = useState<TargetProps | undefined>(
        undefined
    );

    const onCreateClick = () => {
        setTargetRow(undefined);
        setFormModalOpen(true);
    };
    const handleEdit = (row: any) => {
        setTargetRow(row.original);
        setFormModalOpen(true);
}

let arr: any = []; // some data
let newArr: any = []; // some data

    const fieldOptions = () => {
        return [...arr, ...newArr];
    };

    const getInitialData = (
        values: ValueProps
    ): ReturnProps[] => {
        const data = get(values, "gqlMedia");
        return data && Array.isArray(data) ? data.slice() : [];
    };

return (
        <Consumer>
            {(consumerProps: IFormConsumer) => {
                const initialData = getInitialData(consumerProps.values);
            return (
                    <>
                        <Modal
                            isOpen={formModalOpen}
                            onCancel={onFormCancel}
                            targetRow={targetRow}
                            data={initialData}
                            fieldOptions={fieldOptions}
                        />
                        <Table
                            initialData={initialData}
                            handleEdit={handleEdit}
                            onCreateClick={onCreateClick}
                            readOnly
                            fieldOptions={fieldOptions}
                        />
                    <>
                )
            }}
        </Consumer>
    );
};
```

When I move to a page other than the 1st page in the table and edit a row, the edit modal opens. The table is automatically rendering the 1st page in the background. The page should stay when the modal is opened. I don't want the Table component to be rerendered when the modal is opened (the state is changed). Tried using useCallback, useMemo, React.memo. Not able to find a solution.